# Font Awesome Package Not Loading on Chrome

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, font-awesome

I noticed today on my [website](https://www.christopherfrydryck.cf/index.html) that font awesome was not loading on Chrome. It should have a double down arrow in the gradient circle, however it is not showing on Chrome on my laptop.  It did show up on Chrome on my Google Pixel, however I am assuming they may be different versions of the browser since one is for mobile.  It worked fine earlier when I tested it and nothing had changed in my code since it worked fine.  I am beyond confused.

In the head is this:
`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">`

Here is the code for the font-awesome library I am using:

`<div class="arrowContainer">
    <div class="arrow"><i class="fa fa-angle-double-down" aria-hidden="true" 
    style="font-size:36px; color: white"></i></div>
</div>`

Comment: You're not linking to font-awesome using the link you mentioned in the question, but from `http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css`. Load the library over https and you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Your Site is not being delivered with http**s**, either change that or simply change your head link to:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

Only using `//` will choose the appropriate protocol based on your sites protocol